# Javafx Timeline stops playing upon passing through multiple listeners

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm a beginner who recently picked up JavaFX, I've been trying to make a program that executes an animation on a node upon clicking on it. I've tried to see if anyone else has tried something similar but I have not been able to find a similar case to what I've tried to do.

The Timeline animates Panes, which contain a Rectangle and Text, horizontally across the screen, upon finishing the execution the stage will change scenes. When the user clicks a button to go back to the original scene the buttons should perform another animation.

I've verified that it isn't the scene transition that is causing it to stop and I have also verified that the program is indeed executing `.play()` on the timeline. The timelines are executed within the custom listeners so the listeners are not an issue as far as I know.

Here is the code sample to recreate the issue I have, run the script and just press on. Here you can see that `done` is being printed to the console which is right underneath `Main_Button_Animation.play();` however, nothing is being animated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class main extends Application{
    Scene scene1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("test");
        Main_Screen MainScreen = new Main_Screen(800, 480);

        scene1 = MainScreen.MainScreen(primaryStage);
        MainScreen.getInitiater().Calibration_Listener(() -> {
            MainScreen.getInitiater().Back_Button_Pressed();
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
//custom listeners
interface Calibration {
    void menu();
}
interface Back {
    void back();
}
class Initiater {
    private List<Calibration> calilist = new ArrayList<Calibration>();;
    private List<Back> Go_Back = new ArrayList<Back>();

    public void Calibration_Listener(Calibration toAdd) {
        calilist.add(toAdd);
    }
    public void Back_Listener(Back toAdd) {
        Go_Back.add(toAdd);
    }

    public void Calibration_Pressed() {
        System.out.println("Calibration Pressed");
        for (Calibration hl : calilist)
            hl.menu();
    }
    public void Back_Button_Pressed() {
        System.out.println("Back Pressed");
        for (Back hl : Go_Back)
            hl.back();
    }
}

//animations and setup
class Main_Screen {
    Initiater initiater;
    private int X;
    private int Y;

    public Main_Screen(int X, int Y) {
        this.initiater = new Initiater();
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    private Pane UI_Button(String name, int[] pos, int[] size, Color color) {
        final Text text = new Text(0, 0, name);
        text.setFont(new Font(20));

        final Rectangle outline = new Rectangle(0, 0, size[0], size[1]);
        outline.setFill(color);

        final StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(outline, text);
        stack.setLayoutX(pos[0]);
        stack.setLayoutY(pos[1]);

        return stack;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.X;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.Y;
    }

    public Initiater getInitiater() {
        return this.initiater;
    }

    public Scene MainScreen(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), getX(), getY());
        scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        Pane Start = UI_Button("Start", new int[] { getX() - getX() / 4, 0 }, new int[] { getX() / 4, getY() / 4 }, Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
        Pane Calibration = UI_Button("Callibration", new int[] { 0, ((getY() + (getY() / 8)) / 4) * 0 }, new int[] { getX() / 2, getY() / 4 }, Color.rgb(60, 208, 230));

        System.out.println(Calibration.boundsInLocalProperty());
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(Calibration, Start);

        final Timeline Main_Button_Animation = new Timeline();
        final KeyFrame Cali_kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), new KeyValue(Calibration.translateXProperty(), getX() / 2));
        final KeyFrame Start_kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), new KeyValue(Start.translateXProperty(), -getX() / 4));
        Main_Button_Animation.getKeyFrames().addAll(Cali_kf, Start_kf);
        Main_Button_Animation.setRate(-1);
        Main_Button_Animation.jumpTo(Main_Button_Animation.getTotalDuration());
        Main_Button_Animation.play();

        Calibration.setOnMouseClicked(MouseEvent -> {
            Calibration.setDisable(true);
            Start.setDisable(true);
            System.out.println(Calibration.boundsInLocalProperty());
            Main_Button_Animation.setRate(1);
            Main_Button_Animation.jumpTo(Duration.millis(0));
            Main_Button_Animation.play();
            Main_Button_Animation.setOnFinished(event -> {
                Main_Button_Animation.play();
                System.out.println("done");
            });
        });     
        return scene;
    }

}
```

***Edit1*** : For clarity, The example above doesn't use any scene transition. Here is a example with a scene transition.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class main extends Application{
    Scene scene1, scene2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("test");
        Main_Screen MainScreen = new Main_Screen(800, 480);

        scene1 = MainScreen.MainScreen(primaryStage);
        MainScreen.getInitiater().Calibration_Listener(() -> {
            primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
            primaryStage.show();
        });

        Label label2 = new Label("This is the second scene");
        Button button2 = new Button("Go to scene 1");
        button2.setOnAction(e -> {
            MainScreen.getInitiater().Back_Button_Pressed();
            primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
            primaryStage.show();
        });
        VBox layout2 = new VBox(20);
        layout2.getChildren().addAll(label2, button2);
        scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 800, 480);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
//custom listeners
interface Calibration {
    void menu();
}
interface Back {
    void back();
}
class Initiater {
    private List<Calibration> calilist = new ArrayList<Calibration>();;
    private List<Back> Go_Back = new ArrayList<Back>();

    public void Calibration_Listener(Calibration toAdd) {
        calilist.add(toAdd);
    }
    public void Back_Listener(Back toAdd) {
        Go_Back.add(toAdd);
    }

    public void Calibration_Pressed() {
        System.out.println("Calibration Pressed");
        for (Calibration hl : calilist)
            hl.menu();
    }
    public void Back_Button_Pressed() {
        System.out.println("Back Pressed");
        for (Back hl : Go_Back)
            hl.back();
    }
}

//animations and setup
class Main_Screen {
    Initiater initiater;
    private int X;
    private int Y;

    public Main_Screen(int X, int Y) {
        this.initiater = new Initiater();
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    private Pane UI_Button(String name, int[] pos, int[] size, Color color) {
        final Text text = new Text(0, 0, name);
        text.setFont(new Font(20));

        final Rectangle outline = new Rectangle(0, 0, size[0], size[1]);
        outline.setFill(color);

        final StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(outline, text);
        stack.setLayoutX(pos[0]);
        stack.setLayoutY(pos[1]);

        return stack;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.X;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.Y;
    }

    public Initiater getInitiater() {
        return this.initiater;
    }

    public Scene MainScreen(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), getX(), getY());
        scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        Pane Start = UI_Button("Start", new int[] { getX() - getX() / 4, 0 }, new int[] { getX() / 4, getY() / 4 }, Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
        Pane Calibration = UI_Button("Callibration", new int[] { 0, ((getY() + (getY() / 8)) / 4) * 0 }, new int[] { getX() / 2, getY() / 4 }, Color.rgb(60, 208, 230));

        System.out.println(Calibration.boundsInLocalProperty());
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(Calibration, Start);

        final Timeline Main_Button_Animation = new Timeline();
        final KeyFrame Cali_kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), new KeyValue(Calibration.translateXProperty(), getX() / 2));
        final KeyFrame Start_kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), new KeyValue(Start.translateXProperty(), -getX() / 4));
        Main_Button_Animation.getKeyFrames().addAll(Cali_kf, Start_kf);
        Main_Button_Animation.setRate(-1);
        Main_Button_Animation.jumpTo(Main_Button_Animation.getTotalDuration());
        Main_Button_Animation.play();

        Calibration.setOnMouseClicked(MouseEvent -> {
            Calibration.setDisable(true);
            Start.setDisable(true);
            System.out.println(Calibration.boundsInLocalProperty());
            Main_Button_Animation.setRate(1);
            Main_Button_Animation.jumpTo(Duration.millis(0));
            Main_Button_Animation.play();
            Main_Button_Animation.setOnFinished(event -> {
                this.initiater.Calibration_Pressed();
                System.out.println("done");
            });
        });
        this.initiater.Back_Listener(() -> {
            Main_Button_Animation.setRate(-1);
            Main_Button_Animation.jumpTo(Main_Button_Animation.getTotalDuration());
            Main_Button_Animation.play();
            Main_Button_Animation.setOnFinished(e -> {
                Calibration.setDisable(false);
                Start.setDisable(false);
            });
        });
        return scene;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get the desired animation, but you don't seem to change the scene anywhere (just a single call to `setScene`/`setRoot` in the `start` method). Furthermore you only define the target values of the animation making reversing the animation impossible with the same animation object, assuming the keyframes aren't replaced.

Comment: The example doesn't include the scene change to show that the scene change isn't what causes it. I thought it was possible to reverse the animation by setting `setRate(negative value)` and have always done so to change directions if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only define `KeyValue`s for the frame at the end of the `Timeline` animation. This only allows the `Timeline` to interpolate between the value at the start of the animation and the target value. Inserting another `KeyFrame` at the beginning of the animation should fix this issue:

```
public Scene MainScreen(Stage stage) {
    final Group root = new Group();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, getX(), getY());
    scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);

    Pane Start = UI_Button("Start", new int[] { getX() * 3 / 4, 0 }, new int[] { getX() / 4, getY() / 4 }, Color.RED);
    Pane Calibration = UI_Button("Callibration", new int[] { 0, 0 }, new int[] { getX() / 2, getY() / 4 }, Color.rgb(60, 208, 230));

    System.out.println(Calibration.boundsInLocalProperty());
    root.getChildren().addAll(Calibration, Start);

    final Timeline Main_Button_Animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                    new KeyValue(Calibration.translateXProperty(), 0),
                    new KeyValue(Start.translateXProperty(), 0)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500),
                    new KeyValue(Calibration.translateXProperty(), getX() / 2),
                    new KeyValue(Start.translateXProperty(), -getX() / 4)));

    Main_Button_Animation.setRate(-1);
    Main_Button_Animation.playFrom(Main_Button_Animation.getTotalDuration());

    Calibration.setOnMouseClicked(MouseEvent -> {
        Calibration.setDisable(true);
        Start.setDisable(true);
        System.out.println(Calibration.boundsInLocalProperty());
        Main_Button_Animation.playFromStart();
        Main_Button_Animation.setOnFinished(event -> {
            this.initiater.Calibration_Pressed();
            System.out.println("done");
        });
    });
    this.initiater.Back_Listener(() -> {
        Main_Button_Animation.setRate(-1);
        Main_Button_Animation.playFrom(Main_Button_Animation.getTotalDuration());
        Main_Button_Animation.setOnFinished(e -> {
            Calibration.setDisable(false);
            Start.setDisable(false);
        });
    });
    return scene;
}
```

Note that there have been a few additional changes here:

- Combining  `KeyFrame`s at the same time to a single one with multiple `KeyValue`s
- Keep a reference to the scene root to avoid the use of the getter/cast
- Using `playFrom` and `playFromStart` instead of `jumpTo`/`play`
- Simplifications of some of the parameters passed to the `UI_Button` method (rounding could make the result differ by 1 though)
- ...

Comment: I see what you mean now, thank you. I didn't know you also needed to re-reference the initial position of the node. I thought JavaFX would be smart enough to understand that the initial position was zero and to go back to that position, thank you.